# Oracle sql tuning multiple counts and distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey dudes i have the following query running on oracle.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
 T_TRATAMIENTO.CampaignID AS CAMPAIGNID,
 T_TRATAMIENTO.OfferID AS OFFERID,
 T_CALENDARIO.ActualDate AS ACTUALDATE,
 count(CASE T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag WHEN 0 THEN T_TRATAMIENTO.TreatmentSize END) as NUM_OF_OFFERS,
 count(CASE T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag WHEN 1 THEN T_TRATAMIENTO.TreatmentSize END) as NUM_OF_OFFERS_CG,
 count (distinct (case T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag when 0 then T_TRATAMIENTO.OfferHistoryID END)) as NUM_OFF_VERS,
 count (distinct (case T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag when 1 then T_TRATAMIENTO.OfferHistoryID END)) as NUM_OFF_VERS_CG,
 count(distinct (CASE WHEN T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag = 0 and T_ESTATUSCONTACTO.CountsAsContact=1 THEN T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.CustomerID END)) as UNIQUE_RECIPIENTS,
 count(distinct (CASE T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag WHEN 1 THEN T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.CustomerID END)) as UNIQUE_RECIP_CG FROM
 T_ESTATUSCONTACTO,
 T_CALENDARIO,
 T_TRATAMIENTO
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
 T_HISTORIALCONTACTO ON
 T_TRATAMIENTO.PackageID = T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.PackageID
 WHERE
 T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.CellID = T_TRATAMIENTO.CellID
 AND
 T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.ContactStatusID = T_ESTATUSCONTACTO.ContactStatusID
 AND
 T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.DateID = T_CALENDARIO.DateID
 AND
 T_TRATAMIENTO.HasDetailHistory = 0 GROUP BY
 T_TRATAMIENTO.CampaignID,
 T_TRATAMIENTO.OfferID, T_CALENDARIO.ActualDate;
```

Table T_HISTORIALCONTACTO has 80 million records, still growing, other tables just less than 100 records, and there´s timing in response. Also making full scan. I had already implement indexes but still shows slow performance.

How can i tune this sql query? What would u recommend. I really apprecciate ur help. Thanxs in advance

Comment: Seems that table `UA_ContactHistory` is missing in from list. Also you mix old-style with ANSI joins which is bad practice. By the way how many rows from `T_HISTORIALCONTACTO` you select in average with each query run?

Comment: oh sorry i edit the query again.

Comment: What about my question? How many rows you expect from your query before `group by`? Seems that you are not restricting `T_HISTORIALCONTACTO` to any particular period. Do you need your query to return all data stored in `T_HISTORIALCONTACTO`?

Comment: How long does the query currently take?  With 80 million records, and no predicates that look very selective, a full table scan on the large table may be the best choice.  It would help if the explain plan was added to the question.  Run `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  Also, what version of Oracle are you using?  For example, if you're using 11gR2 Enterprise Edition, it may help to add a parallel hint like `select /*+ parallel */ ...`.

Comment: Aprox 30 to 50 records. No restrictions of particular period. Yes I  need to join T_HISTORIALCONTACTO

Comment: It takes too much time, more than 30 minutes.

Comment: why you use so many DISTINCT? are you sure you don't make cartesian join?  besides DISTINCT has poor performance because they do ORDER BY   inside

Comment: SELECT STATEMENT   46M| 9112M| 10700 (100)
 SORT GROUP BY     46M| 9112M| 10700 (100)
  HASH JOIN        46M| 9112M|   888  (97)
  TABLE ACCESS FULL   T_CALENDARIO   5844 | 148K|  18 (0)
  NESTED LOOPS     
  NESTED LOOPS     46M|  7967M|    13   (0)
MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN  772| 90324 |    13   (0)
   TABLE ACCESS FULL  T_ESTATUSCONTACTO  4|  104|   3 (0)
   BUFFER SORT     193| 17563 |    10   (0)
   TABLE ACCESS FULL  T_TRATAMIENTO  193 | 17563 |  3 (0)
 INDEX RANGE SCAN  CCONTACTHIST_LINEA_IX1  4544K | | 0   (0)
     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| UA_CONTACTHISTORY_LINEA | 59790 |  3736K| 0 (0)

Comment: @user2115594 Rather add the plan to the question, not to the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't need first DISTINCT because you have group by on first 3 columns (CAMPAIGNID, OFFERID,ACTUALDATE).
Secondly I recommend avoid "cartesian merge join" which is very consuming. So try this new join approach.
If cartesian join will still occur try to make "join" between these tables: T_ESTATUSCONTACTO, T_CALENDARIO, T_TRATAMIENTO.
Currently you have only separated joins to T_HISTORIALCONTACTO

```
SELECT 
 T_TRATAMIENTO.CampaignID AS CAMPAIGNID,
 T_TRATAMIENTO.OfferID AS OFFERID,
 T_CALENDARIO.ActualDate AS ACTUALDATE,
 count(CASE T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag WHEN 0 THEN T_TRATAMIENTO.TreatmentSize END) as NUM_OF_OFFERS,
 count(CASE T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag WHEN 1 THEN T_TRATAMIENTO.TreatmentSize END) as NUM_OF_OFFERS_CG,
 count (distinct (case T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag when 0 then T_TRATAMIENTO.OfferHistoryID END)) as NUM_OFF_VERS,
 count (distinct (case T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag when 1 then T_TRATAMIENTO.OfferHistoryID END)) as NUM_OFF_VERS_CG,
 count(distinct (CASE WHEN T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag = 0 and T_ESTATUSCONTACTO.CountsAsContact=1 THEN T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.CustomerID END)) as UNIQUE_RECIPIENTS,
 count(distinct (CASE T_TRATAMIENTO.CntrlTreatmtFlag WHEN 1 THEN T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.CustomerID END)) as UNIQUE_RECIP_CG FROM
 T_TRATAMIENTO 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T_HISTORIALCONTACTO ON T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.CellID = T_TRATAMIENTO.CellID
 JOIN T_CALENDARIO  on T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.DateID = T_CALENDARIO.DateID
 JOIN T_ESTATUSCONTACTO on T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.ContactStatusID = T_ESTATUSCONTACTO.ContactStatusID
 WHERE
 T_TRATAMIENTO.HasDetailHistory = 0 
 GROUP BY
 T_TRATAMIENTO.CampaignID,
 T_TRATAMIENTO.OfferID, T_CALENDARIO.ActualDate;
```

Comment: Thanxs Franek, I still have a doubt. In the fixed sql that u post, how do u make the join with T_TRATAMIENTO.PackageID = T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.PackageID ? I´m not sure cause there´s a previous join between those tables T_TRATAMIENTO 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN T_HISTORIALCONTACTO ON T_HISTORIALCONTACTO.CellID = T_TRATAMIENTO.CellID    Thanxs in advance

Comment: You are right, I fixed it. Lower pseudo join (pseudo because it hasn't even proper syntax) should be removed. It's relic from your sql - where you made two joins between T_TRATAMIENTO and T_HISTORIALCONTACTO. Try this sql now and give us feedback ;)

Comment: @user2115594 Thank you for adding the plan, but it got garbled somehow.  Add the *entire* output from `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` to the question.  I think there is a nested loop between the large table but I can't quite make it out from the explain plan you posted.  I would recommend using Franek's query to generate the explain plans; even if it's not any faster the simplification of the joins is very useful.